# data.map is not a function typerror in cart

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
const Cart = ({ details }) => {
  let { loading, data } = details;

  console.log(data);
  

  return (
    <div>
      {loading ? (
        <p>Load</p>
      ) : (
        <table>
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Id</th>
              <th>Title</th>
              <th>Completed</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            {data.map((d) => {
              return (
                <tr key={d.id}>
                  <td>{d.id}</td>
                  <td>{d.title}</td>
                  <td>{d.completed ? "OK" : ""}</td>
                </tr>
              );
            })}
          </tbody>
        </table>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Cart;
```

console log of details is:

```
{
    loading: false, data: {…}}
    data: {data: Array(3)}
    loading: false
   "================="
```

console log of data is

```
{data: Array(3)}

data: Array(3)
0: {userId: 1, id: 1, title: 'delectus aut autem', completed: false}
1: {userId: 1, id: 2, title: 'quis ut nam facilis et officia qui', completed: false}
2: {userId: 1, id: 3, title: 'fugiat veniam minus', completed: false}
length: 3
```

I am getting error:

> Uncaught TypeError: data.map is not a function
> at Cart

Comment: data.data is array

Answer (score 0):

As you said "console log of data is {data: Array(3)}" so "data" is an Object, not an Array.

try `data.data.map((d) => {...})`